# Can not install fairseq==v0.10.2 in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, fairseq

I'm a newer in python. My teacher said me to run this code: https://github.com/shirley-wu/text_to_table. But I can't run it in Pycharm, when I install package it install successfully some package except fairseq==v0.10.2. And show error:

```
Collecting fairseq==v0.10.2
  Using cached fairseq-0.10.2.tar.gz (938 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [30 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 214, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 191, in do_setup
    File "C:\Users\19522\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a4bcv_cg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 106, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "C:\Users\19522\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a4bcv_cg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 79, in _install_setup_requires
      _fetch_build_eggs(dist)
    File "C:\Users\19522\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a4bcv_cg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 84, in _fetch_build_eggs
      dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    File "C:\Users\19522\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a4bcv_cg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 74, in fetch_build_eggs
      raise SetupRequirementsError(specifier_list)
  setuptools.build_meta.SetupRequirementsError: ['cython', 'numpy', 'setuptools>=18.0']
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\19522\text_to_table\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\19522\text_to_table\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\19522\text_to_table\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\19522\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a4bcv_cg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\19522\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a4bcv_cg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\19522\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a4bcv_cg\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 217, in <module>
  PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'fairseq\\examples'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: make sure the process has permission here -> `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'fairseq\\examples'`

Comment: I have run as admin already @abestrad

Answer (score 0):

try this command it worked for me:
`pip install fairseq==0.10.0`